# How to make filter for symbol - in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, wildcard

How to make filter for symbol - in PowerShell

```
Get-ChildItem -Include *-*
```

does not work if my files or folders have names like

Test1-DEV

Test2-Test

Test3-Staging

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `-Path` (the default parameter):

```
Get-ChildItem -Path *-*
```

Or, if you are searching in subdirectories, use the `-Recurse` parameter in combination with `-Include`.

From `Get-Help Get-ChildItem`:

> ```
> -Include <String[]>
>
> Specifies, as a string array, an item or items that this cmdlet includes in the operation. The value of this
> parameter qualifies the Path parameter. Enter a path element or pattern, such as *.txt. Wildcards are
> permitted.
>
> The Include parameter is effective only when the command includes the Recurse parameter or the path leads to
> the contents of a directory, such as C:\Windows\*, where the wildcard character specifies the contents of the
> C:\Windows directory.
>
> Required?                    false
> Position?                    named
> Default value                None
> Accept pipeline input?       False
> Accept wildcard characters?  false
> ```

Comment: [It helps to link to the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/providers/filesystem-provider/get-childitem-for-filesystem?view=powershell-5.1) and explain why what you're doing solves the problem.

Comment: seems working for my task. PowerSheel 3.  and yes I tried combine -include with -Directory.

Comment: @justromagod Glad I could help, may I encourage you to [accept an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it helps, I notice you have a number of posts with no accepted answers.